# Android - Memory usage keep going up on switching Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an `Activity` which holds a LOT of `Fragments`.. Many of those `Fragments` has `RecyclerView` and those which have `RecyclerView` holds an `ArrayList` inside their own `RecyclerViewAdapter`.

First suspicion, all my `RecyclerViewAdapter` constructor looks like : `AdapterName(Context context)` and the `Adapter` has its own `context` variable which could mean that the `context` is always be held by the `Fragment` and causing the memory issue.

Second, still in the `Adapter`, I store all the data I got from API in a variable. The data array is complex, contains mostly `String` or `integer` (some has `boolean`, some has `Object` as in `Object` inside `Object`), but the amount could be.. Massive if user keeps scrolling down.. Android Studio's Memory monitor keep going up every scroll..

Third, something else (or many things) in my `Fragment` aren't destroyed when the `Fragment` is placed in the backstack. Returning from backstack by pressing back also doesn't reduce the memory consumption..

For now I can only have suspicion on those three things because I don't know what else might be the problem.. Anybody can point me to the right direction? Or any memory management advice based on how I manage my `Fragment` content? (If I miss any essential detail, please do notify me)

Comment: Install something like LeakCanary and see if you can detect any memory leaks

Comment: Will do it now, sorry I wasn't at work yesterday, going to google it now

Comment: Hmm I'm at lost in using LeakCanary as it accepts `Application` in its constructor.. I'm fairly new at Android programming, so.. I humbly ask how to do it inside a `Fragment`?

Comment: Just initialise it in your application class, it will then pick up most memory leaks in your app, no extra setup required for Fragments

Comment: I think.. I don't have an Application class..................